# Type Inference in Stream

Tags: scala

Why can't the compiler infer the type of the wildcard in the `filter`?

```
scala> Stream.from(1) takeWhile(_ < 1000) filter ( ( _ % 3  == 0) || ( _ % 5 == 0)) sum

<console>:18: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.$percent(3).$eq$eq(0))
              Stream.from(1) takeWhile(_ < 1000) filter ( ( _ % 3  == 0) || ( _ % 5 == 0)) sum
```

This works fine:

```
scala> Stream.from(1).takeWhile( x => x < 1000).filter(x => (x % 3 == 0) || (x % 5 == 0)).sum
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [SLS 6.23.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions):

> If an expression e binds underscore sections `u1,…,un`, in this order, it is equivalent to the anonymous function `(u′1, ... u′n) => e′` where each `u′i` results from `ui` by replacing the underscore with a fresh identifier and `e′` results from `e` by replacing each underscore section `ui` by `u′i`.

This means that multiple underscores using the placeholder syntax imply an anonymous function with multiple parameters.

i.e.

`(_ > 0)` expands to `(x => x > 0)`

`(_ > 0 || _ < -10)` expands to `((x, y) => x > 0 || y < -10)`

`(_ > 0 || _ < -10 || _ % 2 == 0)` expands to `((x, y, z) => x > 0 || y < -10 || z % 2 == 0)`

And so on.. The error is a little confusing because it *looks* like it's trying to read it as an arity-1 function within each set of parenthesis based on the error message. I'll *speculate* that it then doesn't know what to do with the expression `x => a || y => b` to infer the types to somehow come up with `Int => Boolean`.

Answer (score 3):

Each subsequent instance of `_` refers to the *next* argument. If you want to reuse an argument of a lambda, you must name it like you did in the 2nd version you posted.

The first version desugared would be more like

`filter ((x,y) => ( x % 3  == 0) || ( y % 5 == 0))`